# Always being asked about email and password when interacting with a Git repository on Github

Tags: git, bash, github, ssh

I've followed [GitHubs own guide on how to set up SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) without errors, everything seems to work great. When SSHing to git@github.com I'm greeted with my username and everything.

However, when using `git pull` or any other command that needs authenticating I'm always prompted for details and it's starting to annoy me.

I've tried various different solutions around the web but none has worked. I'm using Git Bash on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you running an ssh agent such as PuTTY's `pageant`? Are you prompted for a password when you SSH to git@github.com or only when doing `git pull`? Did you clone the repo using the URL for HTTP or SSH?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you need to tell git to store your credentials by caching them.

To store your credentials you need to use the following git command:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 3600'
```

This will store your credentials you setup in a separate file under your project directory (.git-credentials).

If you wish Git to resume to asking you for credentials you can run the following command:

```
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: Hey, why the downrate? If someone mark the answer as downrate be so kind and explain the reason why?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would guess the main problem is the OP isn't using the right url for their repo. This answer also duplicates info in the duplicate question (which was flagged as a duplicate before this answer was created iirc - _don't answer duplicate questions_).

Comment: I think you are wrong! I already answered the question before the question was voted as duplicate.

Comment: You are going to ignore the other (more relevant) possible explanation? Again, I didn't downvote your answer.